# Using Highcharts with SPServices jQuery library to create Pie Chart

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, highcharts, spservices

This is my very first [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) project and I'm having some issues displaying the data that I'm fetching using [SPservices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).
I found this tutorial ([SharePoint to Highcharts](http://hubertvdmsp.blogspot.ca/2012/10/sharepoint-to-highcharts.html)) and it helped a lot but I'm having issues showing the names of the columns in the charts and the legend, it only shows "Slice" This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var namesArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "Test",
   CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Person'/></OrderBy></Query>",
   CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Person' /><FieldRef Name='Age' /><FieldRef Name='Earnings' /><FieldRef Name='Names' /></ViewFields>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
var names = $(this).attr("ows_Names");
var values = Math.round($(this).attr("ows_Earnings"));
namesArray.push(names);
valuesArray.push(values);

});  } });  
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total values',
            x: -20, //center
             },

   plotOptions:{ pie: {
allowPointSelect: true,
showInLegend: true,
cursor: 'pointer',
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
color: '#000000',
connectorColor: '#000000',
formatter: function() {
return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: $'+ this.y;} }, }},

        subtitle: {
            text: 'This chart shows value from a SharePoint list using SPServices',
            x: -20
        },

   tooltip:{shared: true,pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.values}$</b>{point.y}',valueDecimals: 2,shared: true,
        useHTML: true,},


        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -300,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
         showInLegend:true,
        type: 'pie',
            name: 'Earnings',
            data: valuesArray
        }]
    });});
```

This is what I see in the browser:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you show the response that you get from `SPServices` ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is what you are asking for(?) From the console:                               ["John"] 
["John", "Charles"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro", "Juan"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro", "Juan", "Ali"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro", "Juan", "Ali", "Cuco"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro", "Juan", "Ali", "Cuco", "Juan"] 
["John", "Charles", "Jim", "Pedro", "Juan", "Ali", "Cuco", "Juan", "Jenny"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide the slice names in your series data array. Try it this way

```
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        var names = $(this).attr("ows_Names");
        var values = Math.round($(this).attr("ows_Earnings"));
        //namesArray.push(names); <-- YOU DON'T NEED THIS
        valuesArray.push([names,values]);
    });  
});
```

For more explaination See the following fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/XzZa4/1/
If you see the data of the series, you will see that, where the slice name has not been provided, there it got a name as `Slice`

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to write thank you in the comments section, but I have to do it....! Brilliant!!!